# Atomic update if current value is less than another value

Tags: java, atomic

I am looking for something like `AtomicInteger` or `LongAddr` that will:

- Increment if value is less than `MAX` where `MAX` is some user-defined value.
- Return a value indicating whether the atomic was incremented.

Use-case:

- I have a queue of tasks.
- Only `MAX` tasks should run concurrently.
- When a new task is added to a queue, I want to run it if the number of ongoing tasks is less than `MAX`

The reason I can't use `AtomicInteger` or `LongAddr` is that they only allow you to compare against a specific value instead of a range of values.

**Clarification**: I don't want the solution to actually execute the task. My use-case involves passing network requests to Jetty. It uses a single thread to drive multiple network requests. Any solution that fires up an `Executor` defeats this purpose because then I end up with one thread per network request.

Comment: Could you use something like a LinkedBlockingQueue to limit the number of items that can be added to the queue

Comment: @user7 I don't want to limit the number of items that can be added to the queue. I want to queue everything but only run `MAX` tasks at a time.

Comment: I don't quite get your use case. What will you do if there is already MAX-1 active tasks?

Comment: Will you decrement the counter once a job is done?

Comment: @user7 Yes. That's the plan.

Comment: Why can't you use AtomicInteger#incrementAndGet() and AtomicInteger#DecrementAndGet()

Comment: You could use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX)`. This will create executor with `MAX` number of threads which means that not more then `MAX` tasks will be executed concurrently.

Comment: @Ivan I will update the question to clarify, but essentially the tasks are network requests. I don't want to spin up a new thread per request. I want to tell Jetty to send a request using its existing NIO.2 mechanism (a single thread drives multiple requests)

Comment: @HemantPatel Yes, I think this will work (Andy Turner just posted a similar solution) but I was hoping to avoid a spin-lock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andy Turner [provided an excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50278620/14731) but I find this solution more readable. Essentially, all we need is `new Semaphore(MAX)` and `Semaphore.tryAcquire()`.

If you dig into the source-code of `Semaphore` you will find that the implementation is similar to Andy's answer.

Here is some sample code:

```
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(MAX);
// ... much later ...
public void addTask(Runnable task)
{
  if (semaphore.tryAcquire())
    task.run();
  else
    queue.add(task);
}

public void afterTaskComplete(Runnable task)
{
  semaphore.release();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `compareAndSet()`:

```
boolean incrementToTheMax(AtomicInteger atomicInt, int max) {
  while (true) {
    int value = atomicInt.get();
    if (value >= max) {
      // The counter has already reached max, so don't increment it.
      return false;
    }
    if (atomicInt.compareAndSet(value, value+1)) {
      // If we reach here, the atomic integer still had the value "value";
      // and so we incremented it.
      return true;
    }
    // If we reach here, some other thread atomically updated the value.
    // Rats! Loop, and try to increment of again.
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think this will work but I was hoping to avoid a spin-lock (for performance reasons). That said, I just opened up the source-code of `Semaphore` and guess what? They do the same thing. I guess there is no magic :) Anyway, I think I will stick to `Semaphore` simply because the code is easier to understand.

Comment: @Gili there is no performance issue here. This is basically how `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet` etc are implemented.